# How to cut a URL with regular expression

Tags: java, html, split

i am trying to chop a string that contains several information in java ..
the text is something like that :

```
<a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a>
```

i am thinking of using the .split method that need regular expression ..
what i want it to split this string into the URL without quotes .. http://...... .com
and then the text between the tags .. this case HootSuite ..

i will appreciate the help
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML parser to extract the `href` attribute? Easier and much less brittle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to do this.  You want to use an XML or HTML parsing suite like [`org.w3c.dom`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html).  Why, you ask?  Because [you can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: +1, I will say though that every time I see this response I know the writer has not written a spider because so much of the internet is severely broken HTML that would not get through even the most lax parsers.

Comment: the thing that might made this task easier is that am parsing always HTML with the same structure ... it is a URL that is sent back by the Twitter API .. always same structure .. but i think a parser will be the best choice

Comment: And the infamous diatribe has saved another soul.

Comment: @AhmadAssaf That fills me with a warm glow of happiness.